# genstrings -s still matches with NSLocalizedString*

Tags: xcode, localization, genstrings

I think this is either a `genstrings` bug or "feature", but wanted to see if anyone has come across this or knows the answer. I was planning on opening a Radar for this.

We use our own localization macro. Let's call it `CustomLocalizedString`. In our code base, it's quite large and we use a lot of 3rd Party libs. For the vast majority of 3rd Party libs, we don't want any of their localized strings if they happen to have them.  When we do want to use their localized strings, we modify the 3rd Party lib to use our `CustomLocalizedString` macro. Since the strings we don't care about are using the `NSLocalizedString*` macros, the thought was this would be a non-issue.

Localization basically started flagging a few strings with problems. After a little research, I realized it was coming from a 3rd Party lib. I then further realized that we were also including other strings that shouldn't be there (we have a large number of strings). These were strings using the `NSLocalizedString*` marco.

So our invocation of `genstrings` is something like:

`genstrings -o output -s CustomLocalizedString`

I actually use `xargs` and `find` to create the file arguments, so for brevity, I'm omitting that part. Based on the output, it looks like `genstrings` puts both `NSLocalizedString` and `CustomLocalizedString` strings into the Localizable.strings file.

To further verify I created a file with this:

```
NSLocalizedString(@"Normal localized string macro", nil);
CustomLocalizedString(@"Custom localized string macro", nil);
```

And ran:

```
genstrings -o out -s CustomLocalizedString localized_string.txt
```

The output was:

```
/* No comment provided by engineer. */
"Custom localized string macro" = "Custom localized string macro";

/* No comment provided by engineer. */
"Normal localized string macro" = "Normal localized string macro";
```

Running `man genstrings` yields this:

```
-s routine
    Substitutes routine for NSLocalizedString.  For example, -s MyLocalString will catch calls to MyLocalString and MyLocalStringFromTable.
```

Which makes it sound like `NSLocalizedString*` macros would get ignored, but this is not the case.

Note I have already re-written the `find` to be able to only include the 3rd Party libs we want to be localized. Our 3rd Party libs are essentially all in one directory. Since there are a lot of devs on the team, I'd rather try and find if I'm missing a flag or something else which would allow me to include the 3rd Party lib directory and have it properly use only the `CustomLocalizedString` macro. Else I can foresee someone not realizing how we are running `genstrings` and we suddenly find out too late that strings we needed localized were not because they were not added into our `genstrings` `find` list.

Comment: I noticed the same problem recently. Did you ever figure this out? Also must note that -s did actually used to work and ignored nslocalisedstring

Comment: Nope, unfortunately not. I submitted a Radar for this, but have yet to hear back from Apple in regards to this. Xcode 6.3 beta is out, so I may try it against that soon to see if it is still problematic.

Comment: I did the exact same thing and excluded parts which didn't need localization. Of course the -s flag would be way nicer and should work. If I find a solution i'll let you know.